# Samsung Chat Service Privacy

Tags: samsung, instant-messaging, chat

I'm trying to find out privacy settings behind the wifi chat offered by... Samsung? Its built into my S10e as an additional chat service with little to no information about it. It's free and enables chat over WiFi and to groups of users who have the feature enabled. It also enables Android users to see when others who have the service are typing like on the iPhone.

My concern is privacy. If it's free, how do I know that I'm not the product here?

The Stack Exchange app won't let me upload a 256KiB image so I've added a URL for the screenshot: [screenshot of new messages feature](https://i.imgur.com/TiVtb2V_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium)

Comment: If this app available of non-Samsung phones? If it is listed in Google PlayStore please edit your question and include a link to this app.

Comment: This is a pre-installed application, not from Google Play. It is apart of the default messages app used for SMS texting. Very curious...